# 'Him or herself' v. 'himself or herself'?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, singular-they, reflexives

I was reading [this article](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/06/03/philosophys-western-bias/) on the New York Times. This sentence caused me some confusion:

> But what I’m teaching are topics such as 5th-century Indian theories of 
>   logical inference, or the concept of qualitative atomism
>   in classical Buddhism: material that is sufficiently obscure that no
>   student, of any background, should be expected at the outset to
>   recognize him or herself in it.

Shouldn't the last part of this sentence be '…himself or herself in it'?

Comment: Naw, it should be *themself*. :)

Comment: Or I suppose you could use a suspended hyphen after him "...to recognize him- or herself in it." Otherwise, I think you're right, it should be *himself or herself*. I usually like tchrist's answers a lot, but this time I think I disagree. I don't like using plural pronouns and possessives with a singular antecedent.

Comment: @JLG It doesn’t work that way.  *Themself* is no more plural than *yourself* is. But it doesn’t matter if it is, because things aren’t notionally plural like that in English, since *they/them/their* are all fully capable of being the unmarked-for-gender singular, and always have been, where always means over the last 600 years.

Comment: @JLG Compare the natural "If someone shows up with their own idea, then them that they can keep it to themselves, because we like ours better than theirs." with insane "If someone shows up with his or her own idea, then him or her that he or she can keep it to himself or herself, because we like ours better than his or hers."  Nobody but nobody speaks like that.  It is unnatural.

Comment: @tchrist, You're right that that example sounds unnatural. I would reword it if presented with that sentence. (Note: My American Heritage Dictionary doesn't even have "themself" in it.) In the OP's sentence, the writer went to the trouble to use *him or herself*, I think he could have gone the distance and used *himself or herself.*

Comment: @JLG It’s not in your dictionary? Really? That’s odd, considering that Google Books has ***908,000*** hits for it. [This one](http://books.google.com/books?id=YOgh41LjnB8C&pg=PT181&lpg=PT181&dq=themself&source=bl&ots=z06d2uQk2Y&sig=7BqelblzHNkunPl1ZH5iW3NrXps&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9tI6UJuVHKLIyQH1-IDoBw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=themself&f=false) is particularly worth reading.

Comment: @tchrist, Interesting. Thank you. I wonder why it's not in the AH Dictionary. (It also shows up with a squiggly line in my browser spellchecker.)

Comment: Related but not the same: [Use of hyphens when writing repeated compound words that has common parts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67619/use-of-hyphens-when-writing-repeated-compound-words-that-has-common-parts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have suggested, **himself or herself** or **him- or herself** are possible and acceptable; I feel that **him or herself** is also fine, and perhaps even better.

---

Although, indeed, *him(-) or herself* looks like illegitimately cutting up a word, this is how I think most people would say it in speech. Speech is normally leading in such cases, unless this gives you clearly unacceptable results.

As to the hyphen, English normally only uses hyphens where they are necessary to avoid ambiguity, as in compound adjectives. This means that many style books will recommend that you hyphenate *an ill-advised proposal*, but not *this proposal is ill advised*, since the latter is not at all ambiguous.

However, some style books will choose to hyphenate even *is ill advised*, for the sake of consistency; there is something to be said for that. But in general, hyphenation is not extremely strict, and it often comes down to common sense. (Notice the contrast with other European languages, such as Dutch, where the hyphen would be mandatory in *hem- of haarzelf* and with all noun adjectives, such as *noun adjective*. I believe the same applies to German. I don't think this construction is even possible in French.)

In the case of two compound words where part of the first one is omitted in ellipsis, as in *him(-) or herself*, I would only add the hyphen if it were required to avoid ambiguity, which is not the case in this example. Hyphens slightly disrupt the flow of reading. I believe Fowler agrees with me here in his *Modern English Usage*. So I would simply write it as the New York Times does:

> No student, of any background, should be expected at the outset to recognize **him or herself** in it.

You could also use *themselves* and change the subject to *students*, use *themselves* with a singular antecedent, or use only *himself*—but let's not rake up that discussion.

Comment: Do you mean *himself **or** herself* in your sentences (like in the OP's question)?

Comment: @JLG: Oops! Yes, fixed. The construction is the same btw.

Comment: I guess so, but if you were to say *himself **and** herself*, couldn't you just say *themselves*?

Comment: @JLG: You could, but you could also use *themselves* instead of *him or herself*. It's just a somewhat different construction (and purist won't be happy). I guess what you are saying is that *themselves* is almost mandatory is nearly all *and* cases; I think you may be right.

Comment: Yes, hyphens are mandatory in German for the most part. Though, we do not have an equivalent to ``him- or herself``, but would instead use a gender-neutral ``sich selbst``. In this term, the word ``sich`` can refer to ``him``, ``her``, ``it`` or ``them``.